# Enter value in cell based on number from another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, vba

If anyone has done anything like below please help.
What I'm looking for is macro that looks at my A2 value and copy that in column D based on value B with "_"(underscore) after it.

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and add your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need 2 loops for this. One looping through column A and one counting up to the value in column B.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteValues()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim aLastRow As Long
        aLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get last used row in col A

        Dim dRow As Long
        dRow = 1 'start row in col D

        Dim aRow As Long
        For aRow = 1 To aLastRow 'loop through col A
            Dim bCount As Long
            For bCount = 1 To .Cells(aRow, "B").Value 'how many times is A repeated?
                .Cells(dRow, "D").Value = .Cells(aRow, "A") & "_" & bCount 'write into column D
                dRow = dRow + 1 'count rows up in col D
            Next bCount
        Next aRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I was in rush to finish my assigned work, therefore I couldn't explain in detail, but your solution worked perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is little short on particulars but this will do what you're asking.

```
dim i as long
with worksheets("sheet1")
    for i=1 to .cells(2, "B").value2
        .cells(.rows.count, "D").end(xlup).offset(1, 0) = .cells(2, "A").value & format(i, "\_0")
    next i
end with
```

Comment: I think you will need a second loop looping through column A to get the desired result.

Comment: *'... looks at my A2 value and copy that in column D ...'*

Comment: ^^ yes, ok. He probably asked just the wrong question.